# Count Operation in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help, I am not at all good with SQL, so please help me out here.

I want to count number of 'p' present corresponding to each name in the table.

Example:

For abc => Count of 'p' is 3

For xyz => Count of 'p' is 2.

```
name                1.26    1.27    1.25    1.24
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
abc                 a       p        p      p
xyz                 p       a        p  
mln                 p       a        p  
foo                 p       a        p
```

Comment: abc => 3 , xyz => 2 ? how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one with `sum`

```
SELECT
`name`,
(SUM(`1.26` ='p') + SUM(`1.27` ='p') + SUM(`1.25` ='p') +SUM(`1.24` ='p') ) `no_of_p` 
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `name`
```

[**See Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f4d8b/1)

Answer (score 1):

Your column names and table structure are weird. But try this.

```
select t2.`name`,
(select count(t1.`1.26`) from t t1 
 where t1.`name` = t2.`name` and t1.`1.26` = 'p') + 
(select count(t1.`1.27`) from t t1 
 where t1.`name` = t2.`name` and t1.`1.27` = 'p') + 
(select count(t1.`1.25`) from t t1 
 where t1.`name` = t2.`name` and t1.`1.25` = 'p') + 
(select count(t1.`1.24`) from t t1 
 where t1.`name` = t2.`name` and t1.`1.24` = 'p') 
as `count`

from t t2;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4110f0/4

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT COUNT(YOUR_TABLE_ID) as count FROM `YOUR_TABLE_NAME` WHERE `YOUR_COLUMN_NAME` = 'p' GROUP BY `name`
```

It i understand you correct